# Parsing a JSON string of 50,000+ characters into a javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, string, json

I'm trying to evaluate a string of 50,000+ characters from an ajax GET request using jquery. On smaller datasets, the code will evaluate it correctly, but firefox throws an error "Unterminated string literal".
After some digging, I tried using external libraries from JSON.org, replacing \n, \r\n, and \r with an empty string (on the server), and encapsulating the eval() with parentheses.

Here is some of the client-side code (javascript):

http://pastebin.com/wsXuN7tb <- Here I've used an external library to do it

After looking through firebug, I noticed that the json string returned by the server was not complete, and was cut off at 50,000 or so characters. I know for a fact the server is returning a valid json string because I dumped it to a file before sending it to the client, but the client ends up receiving a truncated version.

Why is this happening? Is there any way around this?

Comment: Check the response headers, and include them in your answer. Do you see any odd header, such as `Content-Range`?. Also, when you remove all newlines and carriage feeds (`\n\r`), make sure that every line is still OK (semicolons, parentheses, braces, ...).

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary, just CORS headers: http://pastebin.com/9TDdHzSM

Comment: Can you provide a link to the 50kB page + relevant XHR code, so I can check it?

Comment: Also, the json string is sane and can be parsed until something like this happens: {"state":"Online","rel":"Friend","ign":"Silver The Hedgehog","gamename":"Spiral Knights","ingame":"True","steamid":"STEAM_0:1:19011738","avurl":"29/291d18435f94e5e14dbe5d4011ac00b98f545ad9_full.jpg","

Comment: Here's the parsing code: http://pastebin.com/DYy7r4z0  . And here's the (incomplete) response: http://pastebin.com/b6f8wVXy

Comment: Increase the value of the `timeout` variable. Your request might be canceled, when the request exceeds 50 seconds.

Comment: Hm, I've increased it to 100 seconds, but normally it only takes around 5 seconds to complete the request.

Comment: In fact, it's only cutting off the last few characters.... This is the full data that should have been sent:http://pastebin.com/Brk4X9UA

Comment: Are you sure that the `Content-Range` header doesn't exist? I've previously experienced similar issues with media files in Chrome, because of this header. Only the last bytes were missing.

Comment: My HTTP server does not send that header, only these headers: http://pastebin.com/9TDdHzSM. It's not really a "web server", but it can serve up info via GET and POST requests. Is that header necessary? Pretty much sending the previously mentioned headers, dumping the json string, and closing the connection.

Comment: I would use fiddler or curl. Don't trust the otherwise assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the NetworkStream I used in my c# server could not have a buffer that large, so I just wrote half of the buffer, flushed it, and wrote the other half.

Thanks for helping guys.

Answer (score 1):

URLs have a length limit that varies from browser to browser. 50,000+ characters is definitely WAY over every browser's limit. For such large data, you should be using a POST instead.

There is quite literally NOTHING you can do about this limit, as it's a browser limit, and not something you can change on the server. The only thing you can go is switch to using POST.

Comment: That's the request limit. The OP is having issues with the response.

Comment: I'm implementing this as we speak, but I'm curious to know why this is the case. Shouldn't the response body from a GET request and a POST request be the same?

Comment: Turns out the NetworkStream I used in my c# server could not have a buffer that large, so I just wrote half of the buffer, flushed it, and wrote the other half.

Thanks for helping guys.